# How to load SoundCloud track in Buzz audio

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, buzz.js

I'm trying to load a track from SoundCloud into a [Buzz audio](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/sound/) object.  The streaming url redirects as expected when I paste it into my browser, but for some reason does not work correctly when I try to load it in the Buzz object.  I suspect it is the redirect that is breaking it (though I'm not sure why it would).  I've tried a lot of different variations on

```
SC.get('/resolve', { url: track_url }, function(track, err) {
  mySound = new buzz.sound(track.stream_url+'?client_id=201b55a1a16e7c0a122d112590b32e4a');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stupid_genius/yfd8yjgz/2/)

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
I ran the above fiddle on a Linux machine and it ran fine.  I was originally running this on Windows and that's where the problem is occurring.  The `loadstart` event fires and then 1 or 2 `progress` events fire and then nothing else happens.

*Machine where it runs:*
Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
Intel i5; 8 GB
Chromium (fairly recent version)

*Machine where it does not run:*
Windows 7 64-bit
Intel i7; 8 GB
SRWare Iron Version 30.0.1650.0 (230000)
also on Firefox 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the browser.  I'd thought I'd ruled that out by running the fiddle on Firefox v31, but turns out what I'd actually run on FF was one of the variants that didn't work anywhere.  When I tried the fiddle I linked in the question, on Firefox v31 running on the Windows machine, the track played correctly.